# Why do these Azure Functions keep stopping?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a series of three Azure Function apps. All three are running the same code (.NET 6), and they should run every 5 minutes - the CRON expression is `0 */5 * * * *`.

Upon each run, each of these function apps should copy a set of blobs (using the shared access signature) from a source storage container to a target storage container.

What actually happens is that all three of them run, and I can see the details in the function's `Invocation trace` log. And then 5 minutes later they run again. And again. But then sometime later one of them will stop running, and some time after that another will stop running. Within 24 hours all three will have stopped running. And I can't figure out why.

Sometimes they stop for a period, then start running again.

According to each function's invocation traces, there are no errors. And yet you can see from this screenshot that there are gaps.

[image]

Here is one of the other function apps...

[image]

As can be seen on these invocation traces, no errors are reported. However, if I look in `Diagnose and solve problems` there appear to be HTTP trigger errors...

[image]

Why, for a timer-triggered function?

If I look at the `Availability and performance` report I can see that some errors *have* occurred...

[image]

If so, why are these exceptions not reported on the `Invocation traces` view? Furthermore, I've try/catch'd the hell out of this thing, and if an exception occurs it should be both logged and emailed. And yet no exceptions have been logged or emailed.

If I restart the function apps they *usually* start up again, although once or twice I've had to rename the function itself, and then it restarts.

Some final details about the function apps:

- Consumption plan
- Each app is in a different data centre location and separate app service plan
- Each run - when they run - takes 30-40 seconds
- The Azure subscription is billed via a corporate credit card and there are no outstanding bills

Comment: the mention of "archived blobs" is somewhat weird. Are you doing any lifecyle policies etc on the backing storage accounts, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I have a rule which sets blobs to `Archive` 1 day after creation in the target container. In addition, before copying the blob to the target container the code checks whether a) a blob with the same name exists in the target container, and b) if such a blob is in the `Archive` tier; if _yes_ to both, it should log this, send an email, and then continue to the next blob.

Comment: yeah...I would rather not do that on a storage account that is being used by the Function to track its internal workings. I'm pretty sure thats the source of your problems

Comment: Can you be clearer on _what_ you think is a bad idea? Archiving the blobs a day after they were copied to the target container?

Comment: the storage account behind the Azure Function is being used for internal workings of it, e.g. for Timer-triggered functions. By you changing tiers of the blobs etc. you are messing with that. Usually I would use a dedicated storage account for the backing store - and not enforce any lifecycle policies etc on that account.

Comment: So you think it would make a difference if the function app was running on a separate storage account than where the blobs are being copied to?

Comment: how about...you just give it a try?

Comment: @silent If you can put your suggestion into an answer then I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: just did. So I take it this did solve your problem?!

Comment: Yes, I wasn't aware that timer-triggered function apps run atop a series of blobs. I modified my Lifecycle Management Rule to only archive those blobs with a tag/index (which obviously the blobs for the function app don't have). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage account behind the Azure Function is being used for internal workings of it, e.g. for Timer-triggered functions. By you changing access tiers of the blobs etc. through life cycle policies, you are messing with that.

Usually, I would recommend to use a dedicated storage account for the backing store - and not enforce any lifecycle policies etc. on that account.